# que la pantalla no se cierre al sacar una captura con openCV python 3.7

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
key = cv2. waitKey(1)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    try:
        check, frame = webcam.read()
        print(check) #
        print(frame) #
        cv2.imshow("Cámara de Seguridad", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('s'): 
            cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
            webcam.release()
            img_new = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            img_new = cv2.imshow("Imagen Capturada", img_new)
            cv2.waitKey(2650)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            print("Procesando la Imagen...")
            img_ = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
            print("Converting RGB imagen a escala de grises...")
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            print("Converted RGB image to grayscale...")
            print("redimencionado imagen a 25x35 scale...")
            img_ = cv2.resize(gray,(28,28))
            print("Redimencionado")
            img_resized = cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img-final.jpg', img=img_)
            print("Imagen guardada")

            break
        elif key == ord('q'):
            print("Apagando Camara")
            webcam.release()
            print("Camera apagada")
            print("programa finalizado.")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print("Apagando Camara")
        webcam.release()
        print("Camera apagada")
        print("Programa finalizado.")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

En el `if` te sobran tres líneas:

- **`webcam.release()`**: si liberas la cámara, en la siguiente iteración el frame será `None` y provocará una excepción en `imshow`.
- **`cv2.destroyAllWindows()`** obviamente.
- **`break`**: esto rompe el ciclo `while` cunado caes en el `if` (captura) que es lo que no quieres. Esto no ocasiona que la ventana se cierre, pero quedará congelada al no actualizarse con nuevos frames.

Con esto la ventana no se cerrará cuando generes una captura.